# Query on Android Call log skips first record

Tags: android, database, cursor, call, calllog

I am trying to fetch all the calls in the android call log using this code:

```
ArrayList<Call> list = new ArrayList<Call>();
    Cursor cursor;
    // The fields we want to select from the internal database. Setting this
    // to null is equivalent to * (e.g., SELECT * FROM...)
    String[] projection = {CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.TYPE};
    String sortOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " desc";
    int numberCol = 0;
    String contactName;
    String contactNumber;
    String contactDate;
    int callType;
    Call phone_call;

    // Query the CallLog table, selecting only the number and date then sorting it by the date.
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, sortOrder);

    numberCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
          //do stuff
        }
    }

    cursor.close();

    return list;
```

This works, for most calls, except for the top one (the newest, since I order by date, descending).

How could this be?

Answer (score 3):

```
cursor.moveToFirst()
```

will move to the first row. So far so good. But then you're doing

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
}
```

which again moves cursor, this time to the next row, which is second one, thus skipping first row.

Answer (score 1):

Melquiades is correct about the source of your problem, however your solution has a problem. [SQLiteDatabase.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is positioned before the first element which is why your while loop is working at the moment, however you are not checking if the cursor returned by the query has any elements in it.

Here is a snippet which both checks for an empty cursor and doesn't skip the first element.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // Handle each element of the query
    } while (cursor.moveToNext())

} else {
    // cursor contains no results
}
```